# How I can active $record

Tags: codeigniter-2, record

I have table like this

```
 public function getDoctorPhotoRecord($count)
    {
        $this->db
            ->select('u.id, fullname, image, unvan_code, baslik, onayli')
            ->from('user as u')
            ->join('user_detail as ud', 'u.id = ud.id')
            ->join('tanim_sehir as us', 'ud.sehir_code = us.code')
            ->where('group', 'doktor')
            ->where('image != \'\' ')

            ->order_by('rand()')
            ->limit($count);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

and I want this code work as

```
<?php
                            $onay = $record->detail->onayli;
                            ?>

                            <?php
                            if ($onay == 0) {
                            ?>
                            <a  href="iletisim" class="font14"><i class="fa fa-user-md" aria-hidden="true"></i> Bu <b>Doktor</b> siz misiniz?</a>

                            <?php
                            } else {
                            ?>
                            <span class="verified" id="verifyuser" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Onaylı Üye"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>

                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
```

When I tried it getting data with this :

```
<?php echo  $item['onayli'];?>
```

but I want active This code

```
<?php
                            $onay = $record->detail->onayli;
                            ?>
```

How I can active this code ?

Thank you

Comment: return object not array using $query->result();

Comment: I dont understand what you mean :S

Comment: You are returning array in your query from your model "return $query->result_array();" just return object like"return $query->result();" for more info https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html